# Adding jQuery UI to Greasemonkey script fails with external CSS file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to add jquery-ui to a Greasemonkey script. my full code: `test.user.js`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Test
// @namespace      rajat.khandelwal
// @description    Test script
// @include        *
// @require        js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
// @require        js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
// @require        css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css

// ==/UserScript==
alert('hi');
```

and In current directory I added JS and CSS directory. It throws error saying `syntax error in css`

```
Error: syntax error
Source File: file:///C:/Users/Rajat/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/poxivdqy.default/gm_scripts/test/jquery-ui-1816custom.css
Line: 13
```

Line 13 is:

```
.ui-helper-hidden { display: none; }
```

What is the problem? How can I add jquery-ui and use it in my userscript?

Comment: We need the lines before and after aswell, it might be possible you missed a `}` in the prev class and it throws the error on the next line since you can't open a new class when the other isn't closed.

Comment: @Niels : not much code. I've updated the question with my full code. 

And line 13 is line 13 in `jquery-ui-1816custom.css` I just copied the file as it is. Can't be a code problem there.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`// @require` currently only works with javascript files.  That error is from trying to parse CSS as JS.

Use `// @resource` for CSS files, like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   rajat.khandelwal
// @description Test script
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
// @require     js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
// @resource    customCSS css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==

var newCSS = GM_getResourceText ("customCSS");
GM_addStyle (newCSS);

alert('hi');
```

---

However, jQuery-UI CSS makes heavy use of background images.  Images that are included via relative paths.

To get the maximum effect of jQuery-UI CSS, I no longer recommend adding it via `GM_addStyle()`.

**Use an injected `<link>` as shown in [this complete, jQuery-UI example userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468928/331508).**

Comment: I am using FireFox v.21. I did what you mentioned here I called jquery ready() function and tried to alert *newCSS* . it did not show up anything

Comment: GM has changed since this answer was first posted.  Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Unfortunately injected `<link>` doesn't work on sites which set `Content-Security-Policy` to a value which prohibits loading CSS from ajax.googleapis.com (or wherever the `<link>` points to.