# Greasemonkey script does not load external JS and CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I am exactly doing what Brock Adams mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688330/adding-jquery-ui-to-greasemonkey-script-fails-with-external-css-file) but I am not being able to see alert at all. I have put all my files in same folder where user script exist but some how it is broken and I can't trace it either.

I am on Firefox version 21

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That linked answer was from 2011, and Greasemonkey has changed a lot since then.  (Note, I just now updated that answer to reflect the changes.)

Basically, you need to use [`@grant` directives](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) now.  If you looked on Firefox's error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), you might have seen error messages like:

> **GM_addStyle is not defined**

Here is a bare-bones addition of jQuery-UI to demonstrate the process:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js
// @resource jqUI_CSS  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==

var jqUI_CssSrc = GM_getResourceText ("jqUI_CSS");

GM_addStyle (jqUI_CssSrc);
```

Comment: I did not see that particulr error. It worked fine when I used inline css and assign to _Gm_addStyle. Also while I would like to convert my GM script into FireFox extension, what if GM is not installed on machine, will **GM_** work?

Comment: I am using GM 0.922 which I downloaded from Mozilla website. Where can I get new one?

Comment: I updated GM version. On putting _grant_ I get error, *this.stringbundle is undefined* and it is comong on the line which does not exist either!

Comment: On the other note, CSS on my local hard disk on same folder of GM script is not being loaded at all

Comment: Am I going crazy? or is this out of date again? I keep seeing this suggestion, but I'm getting the error: `ReferenceError: GM_getResourceText is not defined` even though I have both marked with `@grant`

Comment: @isaaclw, If you are using Greasemonkey version 4 or later. [**Don't.**](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html)