# jQuery-UI is not working in my userscript without CSS, or with customization?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I only want to use a tiny part of jQuery-UI (Menus) in a userscript I am making. jQuery-UI offers custom downloads, but I cannot find any links to specific modules, that I can `@require` in the script. Does anyone host the individual modules?

Also, I have tried just requiring `code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js`, and the script crashes.
Do I need to include some CSS with it as well? And also do some messy looking changes, like according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528541/why-doesnt-my-jquery-ui-script-execute-in-greasemonkey-it-runs-in-the-firebug)? Will that code be different for different JQUI versions? If I am only using a small part of the UI, does that change what I can safely delete/not download?

I would of thought that this would be a popular thing, with official tutorials. But I am not seeing many resources on how to deal with JQUI in userscripts.

I'm running Tampermonkey on Chrome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with userscripts and jQuery-UI is that jQUI uses CSS with lots of background images, all loaded with relative paths. EG:

```
... url("images/ui-bg_dots-small_35_35414f_2x2.png") ...
```

For security reasons, that relative path will seldom work out for a userscript.

This means that to use jQUI in a userscript you can either:

- Load the required CSS off a server. (Dynamically, not using `@resource`)
  **or**
- Use dynamic CSS rewriting as shown in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532646/331508).

I now recommend just using one of [the standard themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) (See the *Gallery* tab in the left-hand column), and using [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui).  Google hosts all of the default jQUI themes such as *UI lightness*, etc.

No one hosts partial jQUI builds for public consumption as far as I've ever found. But, since you are using `@require`, the JS loads from your local machine anyway (very fast), so you might as well save maintenance headaches and use the standard `jquery-ui.min.js` file.

If you really want [a custom jQUI build](http://jqueryui.com/download/), or a heavily customized CSS theme, you will need to have your own server and host the files from there.

Here's a complete Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script that shows how to use jQUI the easy way. The trick is to *inject* the CSS with a `<link>` node so that all the hosted background images will load correctly:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Add stuff to a web page using jQuery UI.
// @include     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

/*--- For this to work well, we must also add-in the jQuery-UI CSS.
    We add the CSS this way so that the embedded, relatively linked images load correctly.
    (Use //ajax... so that https or http is selected as appropriate to avoid "mixed content".)
*/
$("head").append (
    '<link '
  + 'href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.min.css" '
  + 'rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'
);

//--- Add our custom dialog using jQuery.
$("body").append ('<div id="gmOverlayDialog"><h1>Sample Dialog added using jQuery-UI</h1></div>');

//--- Activate the dialog.
$("#gmOverlayDialog").dialog ( {
    modal:      false,
    title:      "Draggable, sizeable dialog",
    position:   {
           my: "top",
           at: "top",
           of: document
           , collision: "none"
    },
    width:      "auto",
    minWidth:   400,
    minHeight:  200,
    zIndex:     3666
} )
.dialog ("widget").draggable ("option", "containment", "none");

//-- Fix crazy bug in FF! ...
$("#gmOverlayDialog").parent ().css ( {
    position:   "fixed",
    top:        0,
    left:       "4em",
    width:      "75ex"
} );
```

---

For minor theme adjustments, you can use `GM_addStyle()` to set `!important` styles.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the official JQuery domain files? `code.jquery.com` vs `ajax.googleapis.com` (never seen Google "Apis" mentioned before)

Comment: And all these images linked to in the CSS. They will NOT be downloaded if I never use them, or they all will be pre-downloaded?

Comment: Google has *seemed* to be faster and have higher uptime. Plus, I figure the bandwidth has less of a financial impact on them and it's one less domain that can track my movements (Google's already got their hooks into almost every page I view). ... That said, use `code.jquery.com` if you wish; there should be no problem with that.

Comment: CSS BG images are not preloaded in general.  I don't *think* that jQUI does anything to preload images (they might in the future), but you'd be surprised how many times a BG image appears.  For example, the sample script in my answer just shows a simple dialog, but it causes 6 background images to be used and downloaded by the theme! ... Fortunately, Google is pretty good about caching.

Comment: Very helpful answer. However, I run into problems with loading mixed conent when accessing HTTPS page. To fix this `href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.min.css"` should be used, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18251129/1071508

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on sites which set `Content-Security-Policy` to a value which prohibits loading CSS from ajax.googleapis.com (or wherever the `<link>` points to.