# Get error just Importing library (via @require) in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to import [dragtable.js](https://github.com/akottr/dragtable/blob/master/jquery.dragtable.js) in my Tampermonkey script, but I am getting this error (jQuery is already in my website) :

> [Error] ERROR: Execution of script 'DragTable' failed! undefined is
>   not a function (near '...$.widget...')    error   (anonymous function)
>   (userscript.html:2:186) ... ...

Here is my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         DragTable
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://localhost:9010/*
// @require https://rawgit.com/akottr/dragtable/master/jquery.dragtable.js

// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
```

How can I import it without the error? Tks

Comment: Seems you need to import jquery also.

Comment: my website already has it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [*dragtable*'s ReadMe](https://github.com/akottr/dragtable/blob/master/README.md), that library **requires both *jQuery* and *jQuery UI*.**

From the error listed, it seems that *jQuery UI* is not present.

So, your script should be, at a minimum:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        DragTable, getting started
// @match       http://localhost:9010/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js
// @require     https://rawgit.com/akottr/dragtable/master/jquery.dragtable.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
```

But, see [this other Q&A for a more details about *jQuery UI* in a userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468276/jquery-ui-is-not-working-in-my-userscript-without-css-or-with-customization).